# Order Inconsistency using sort values operation

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a column in my data frame which has only 1's. But if I take the first 16 rows and do a sort values operation on the column, I get one order but when I take the first 17 rows and perform the same sort values operation, I get a different order. Why is the order changing when there is no change in the value added with respect to the above values present in the column?
[image]

[image]

Comment: It probably uses different sorting algorithms depending on the size of the df. The algorithm for small dataframes is table, the one for larger dataframes is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a stable sorting algorithm: `'mergesort'`. The default uses `'quicksort'`. The [`np.sort` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort) has useful links and comparisons of the different methods.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rank': [1]*40})

df.head(17)['Rank'].sort_values()
#0     1
#14    1
#...
#1     1
#7     1
#16    1
#Name: Rank, dtype: int64    


df.head(17)['Rank'].sort_values(kind='mergesort')
#0     1
#1     1
#2     1
#...
#15    1
#16    1
#Name: Rank, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great. It is working now as expected. Appreciate your help!